# How to style div as below using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create div contain list of prizes as below picture.

Can you help me please??

**Bootstrap:**

[image]

Comment: We'll be glad to help once you show some effort to create this yourself and get stuck somewhere in the middle of the proccess.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained yourself. Are you talking about using an accordion. if so please see this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp